# Friendly URLs in phalcon framwork is not working in Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, phalcon

### I have tried these two codes. but It is not working. It need to access public folder too.

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial.html

### #www/tutorial/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
    RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

### #www/tutorial/public/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: and mod_rewrite is active?

Comment: I dont know how to do it.

Comment: I tried this " sudo a2enmod rewrite", it says "Module rewrite already enabled". I think mod_rewrite enabled.

Comment: My localhost folder is www/html/...     not www/...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `mod_rewrite` is enabled, my guess is that your server isn't  with the `AllowOverride` option properly set...

All **.htaccess** files are ignored by default in apache because someone can manage to upload a **.htaccess** file to your server and override your server configurations. If you're sure that your server's file system is protected you can explicit in the server's configuration that your settings can be overridden by any `.htaccess` file in your directories.

This is done via the `AllowOverride` setting. Refer to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all) to understand a bit more about this.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works... in case you are on ubuntu edit the file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf (here we have an example of /var/www) 
        "AllowOverride All", next ->
                                                  sudo service apache2 restart                                      it was very helpful for me.

Comment: Thank you very much! [cvsguimaraes](http://stackoverflow.com/users/741981/cvsguimaraes)

Answer (score 1):

in case you are on ubuntu edit the file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf (here we have an example of /var/www)

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and change it to;

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

then

sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: copied from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all)